# Execute code before cache is cleared

Tags: 8, caching

I want to execute code before cache is cleared, for example for the menu cache:

```
// Clear menu cache
$cache = \Drupal::cache('menu');
$cache->deleteAll();
```

I want to intervene when the cache clear is called, right before it is deleted. I've read the documentation on [Drupal::cache](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3Acache/8.2.x) and the [Cache API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.api.php/group/cache/8.2.x) but didn't find a solution. Do note that I want to do this using core code only, no contributed modules.

Comment: I think you'll need to provide your own cache classes to do that; none of the core classes invoke events or hooks in `::deleteAll` or `::deleteMultiple` which is where it would need to happen

Comment: Exactly, thanks for your input. Could you provide a code sample to get me started?

Comment: Why do you need this? It is a *cache*, caches are not persistent. Whatever you try to do there will not be reliable, especially with alternative cache backends like redis/memcache which will just drop your cache entries if the memory is used up

Comment: It's for the following core isse: [Standard profile: make "Home" menu link to <front> editable/deletable](https://www.drupal.org/node/2838106). We're removing a link from `standard.links.menu.yml` and adding it with `MenuLinkContent::create()` instead. And now we need an upgrade path.

Comment: Ah of course, just saw the update there. Yeah, forgot about the update path, alex pott saving us again :) I don't think that will work, adding a new hook won't exist yet in the cache either. So it won't be called..

Comment: @Berdir I'm working on this during the Drupal core #SprintWeekend so feel free to jump in today!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't clean but I'm able to do this with [hook_cache_flush](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!core.api.php/function/hook_cache_flush/8.2.x). It's called when a cache clear has been called, before the cache has been cleared.